# Android ViewPager adapter modify other pages

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager, fragmentstatepageradapter

I have a Viewpager that uses a FragmentStatePagerAdapter. Each page is a Fragment. My pages contains an linearlayout (llTags) which is default visible.

If the user clicks on a page (main layout of the fragment), the linearlayout must be invisible (works) but the other linearlayouts (llTags in other pages) needs to be changed too.

If i click, the visibility of the linearlayouts changed off all pages exept the previous and next. 
This is because the getItem from the adapter isn't called for the next/previous item again.
How can i notify these pages.

ps: i have a newInstance method and a public void setTagslayoutVisible(boolean) for changing the visibility from the adapter.

Comment: can we see some code ?

Comment: adapter: http://pastebin.com/RGPkJgCV fragment page: http://pastebin.com/UTDADYZx I know i need to change the data inside a bundle (doing that now)

Answer (score 0):

Next and previous are already loaded and the adapter is not going to call creation.

Take a quick try at this, in your adapter get function if your fragment is already loaded it returns those objects. So just add something like this

```
if(myMap.containsKey(position))
{
      LiveStreamFullScreenFragment lfsf = (LiveStreamFullScreenFragment) myMap.get(position));
      lfsf.setShowTags(mShowTags);
      return lfsf;
} else
{
```

and in your fragment class

```
public void setShowTags(boolean showtags)
{
    mShowTags = showtags;
    if(!mShowTags)
    {
         llLiveStreamTags.setVisibility(View.GONE);
    }
}
```

Hope this helps and enjoy your work.

Comment: Tnx but doesn't work. I fixed it with on another way. Using the constructor of my fragment instead of newInstance and setting a static int for my index.

Comment: You are welcome as long as it works and you share your experience.